# import telegram.ext ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telegram.ext'; 'telegram' is not a package

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

i'm trying to make a telegram bot
but when I try to use

```
import telegram.ext
```

it says

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCPDe.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2tvt.png)

i tried to uninstall and install pip and pip3

```
pip install telegram
pip install python-telegram-bot
```

didn't work then I un-install and then do this code

```
pip3 install telegram
pip3 install python-telegram-bot
```

Comment: Maybe it's a env problem. Did you do pip install with the env active, and is VSCode python interpreter linked to the env?

Comment: What does this output: `pip -V`?